# Is there a way to find what are the download requests my machine is getting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, download, data-transfer

I am trying to download some bat file to a remote machine through a software I made. While some remote machines got the download, some of them haven't. Is there a way I can see if that remote machine got my download request? And whether it declined it? Are there any networking applications or any other way of finding this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Wireshark you can capture the packets and see exactly what communications occured with which IP addresses.  If there is a ton of activity so wireshark will fill with 10k+ entries for you to parse/filter through.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `netstat -b` which will show you which process has which port open.

You can check event viewer by running `eventvwr` and look to see if anything appears relevant.

Since you wrote this software, can you not write in error checking on both ends to see why the sending is being rejected or errors on receiving?